# Unable to open a new tab or new window in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a new tab in Chrome using Keys.CONTROL + "t" but its not working.
Here's the code

```
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Downloads/New folder/chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");               
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

After executing the script, chrome is launched and google.com is loaded, but new tab is not being opened.

OS: Win-10

Selenium version: selenium-java-3.13.0

Chrome Version: Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Is it some issue with selenium 3.13.0 or am i doing something incorrectly.

PS: I tried using JavascriptExecutor and it is working fine. I need to know why **`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");`** is not working properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try JavascriptExecutor

Comment: @iamsankalp89:  as ive already mentioned in the question at the end, i have tried using JavascriptExecutor and thats working fine.:)                   
I want to know what im doing wrong while using Ctrl + t, and if so how to correct it. Thanx

Comment: Try my updated answer. it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

Try this answer it is working fine for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/sankalp.gupta/Desktop/JAVASELN/chromedriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Ready to launch the browser");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");  
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://google.com");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
//Simulate pressing many keys at once in a "chord". 
String openNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(openNewTab);
```

Let me know, if you are still facing any issues.

Comment: hey, i tried the above code, but still nothing happens.
Observing the same behaviour. Chrome is launched and google is loaded. Thats it.
No error and no new tab being opened.

Comment: oh ok, not sure what is the issue. I will investigate and revert, if I find any solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I was not able to make it work. There might be some issue with chrome driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try with robot class

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to open a new tab/window and Check if a new tab is open.
If open, switch to that window.

```
windows1 = driver.window_handles
driver.execute_script('window.open()')
windows2 = driver.window_handles
new_windows = list(set(windows2) - set(windows1))
if len(new_windows) == 0:
  print 'ERROR: no new tabs found'
elif len(new_windows) > 1:
  print 'ERROR: multiple new tabs found: ' + new_windows
else:
  new_window = new_windows[0] 

driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
```

Comment: @ Raj Kamal: using Javascript Executor is working fine.
I want to know why im unable to open a new tab / window by using Ctrl + t

Comment: I haven't tried the keys combination to open a new tab. However, it looks like a chromedriver limitation. Check this bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=581